# created dynamic lazylist with image loader

Tags: android

some body help me..

it's my logcat :

```
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dharma.aplikasilokomedia/com.dharma.aplikasilokomedia.DetailLoko}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.dharma.aplikasilokomedia.FileCache.<init>(FileCache.java:17)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.dharma.aplikasilokomedia.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:32)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.dharma.aplikasilokomedia.DetailLoko.<init>(DetailLoko.java:28)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-10 14:53:02.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     ... 11 more
```

DetailLoko.java :

```
public class DetailLoko extends Activity {

public ImageLoader imageLoader;
{

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(null);
}


JSONArray string_json = null;

String idberita;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
public static final String TAG_JUDUL = "judul";
public static final String TAG_GAMBAR = "gambar";
private static final String url_detail_berita = "http://10.0.2.2/lokomedia/lokoandro/detailberita.php";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    idberita = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);


    new AmbilDetailBerita().execute();

}

class AmbilDetailBerita extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { 

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetailLoko.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu ... !");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idberita",idberita));

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_detail_berita, "GET", params1);
                    string_json = json.getJSONArray("berita");

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                                TextView judul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.judul);
                                TextView detail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
                                TextView isi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);

                        try {
                            // ambil objek member pertama dari JSON Array
                            JSONObject ar = string_json.getJSONObject(0);
                            String judul_d = ar.getString("judul");
                            String detail_d = ar.getString("hari")+" , "+ar.getString("tanggal")+" Diposting Oleh : "+ar.getString("username");
                            String isi_d = ar.getString("isi"); 

                        judul.setText(judul_d);
                        detail.setText(detail_d);
                        isi.setText(isi_d);

                        imageLoader.DisplayImage(ar.getString(TAG_GAMBAR),thumb_image);             
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.home:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        finish();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LokoUtama.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;

    case R.id.exit:
        keluar();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}    
public void keluar(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setMessage("Apakah Anda Ingin" + " keluar?")
     .setCancelable(false)
     .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     finish();
     }
     })
     .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     dialog.cancel();
     }
     }).show();
    }
```

}

FileCache.java :

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context) {

    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LazyList");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url) {

    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear() {
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    if (files == null)
        return;
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
}
```

}

ImageLoader.java :

public class ImageLoader {

```
MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }


        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}


class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: what this will do  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(null);?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial, any suggestions?please

Answer (score 0):

```
     Use this in postExecute()

           judul.setText(judul_d);
           detail.setText(detail_d);
           isi.setText(isi_d);
           imageLoader.DisplayImage(ar.getString(TAG_GAMBAR),thumb_image);
```